# Authentication Failed for Git push to Azure

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, git-push

I am trying to deploy a web app to Microsoft Azure. Everything works succesfully in creating the app and it appers in the Azure portal. When I try to push my repo to Azure it asks me to enter my user credentials with an password authentication popup like the php quickstart said. The problem is whenever I enter the password which I know is right I get this error in git bash:

```
     fatal: Authentication failed for 
     'https://xxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/xxxxxxxxxx.git/'
```

I have seen a few answers where they say to use a url with :443 at the end and I found that url on the azure portal, but whenever I try to add that url remote I get this error:

```
 error: remote azure already exists.
```

I have tried resetting my password and that does not work either.
If anyone could help with just one of these problems that would be awesome. Comment if I can add anything or if I should clarify somthing. Thank you!

Comment: Could it be only due to the fact that you should not use your password but instead use a personal access token? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

Comment: @philippe a Azure Static Website isn't the same thing as azure DevOps. It's tokens won't do any good here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Looks like  remote with the name  **azure**  already exists on your system and that remote contains the url "**[https://******.scm.azurewebsites.net/***.git](https://adamsives@nodejswebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/nodejswebapp.git)**".
- The error message says that, The remote already exists.
- You are trying to add a remote called "azure" that it already exists in your configuration.
- Add a new remote with new name like  **"newazure"**  with it's URL as you want.
- Follow the below command to add new:-

```cs
git remote add newazure https://***.scm.azurewebsites.net/***.git
```

### OR

- Remove the remote  `azure`  first, then add again with the path.

```
$ git remote rm azure
$ git remote add azure <repo-url>
```

**Another way:**
Set the  `azure's`  url instead of adding.

```
$ git remote set-url azure <repo-url>
```